# iptables couldn't load target allow

Tags: networking, security, iptables, firewall

I am using the command below to allow all traffic from hosts on my internal network but it says "iptables v1.4.18: Couldn't load target `ALLOW':No such file or directory". What is the problem here?

```
iptables -A input -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ALLOW
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target isn't `ALLOW` it should be `ACCEPT`.

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

*excerpt iptables man page*

> TARGETS
>
> A  firewall  rule specifies criteria for a packet, and a target.  If the 
>       packet does not match, the next rule in the chain is the examined; if it 
>       does match, then the next rule is specified by the value of the target, 
>       which can be the name of a user-defined chain or one of the special values 
>       **ACCEPT**, **DROP**, **QUEUE**, or **RETURN**.
>
> **ACCEPT** means to let the packet through.  **DROP** means to drop the packet on 
>       the floor.  **QUEUE** means to pass the packet to userspace (if supported by the 
>       kernel).  **RETURN**  means  stop  traversing this chain and resume at the next 
>       rule in the previous (calling) chain.  If the end of a built-in chain is 
>       reached or a rule in a built-in chain with target **RETURN** is matched, the 
>       target specified by the chain policy determines the fate of the packet.

Comment: When I changed my command like that it said "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name."(Ubuntu). But it worked correctly on openSUSE.

Comment: Make it a upper case INPUT.

Comment: @Mr.White - np, thanks for the Q. Glad to have helped.